# Connect to SQL Server installed on vmware from outside

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-workstation

I have `windows server 2008 r2 sp1` on my vmware, `SQL Server 2012 Express` installed there.

I want to use `Sql Server management studio` to connect to the Sql Server from outside (host, and other machines that share the same network) What should I do?

The vmware OS configured as bridge connection with the host, also I enabled the VNC.

Comment: What is your exact trouble? Do you have network connectivity to the virtual machine from the "outside" at all? Do you need help with the Firewall settings? Do you need help with configuring SQL Server to accept network connections?

Comment: i cant connect to the sql server instance, although I can ping to vmware os from another machine that is in the same network. I guess I did configure sql server to accept remote connections. what do you want me to check?

Comment: Being able to ping the machine doesn't mean sql server is accepting remote connections.  It just means the machine is pingable. Paping (http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fpaping%2F&ei=fCZpUd7THc-n0wWTo4DQCQ&usg=AFQjCNFkLbKEmBMuawQm0pIJ2K_A83aSOw&sig2=gkB6j3b670rO1i-n6rndjw&bvm=bv.45175338,d.d2k) is a useful tool for checking other ports.  Use it to ping 1433 on the machine's ip address.

Answer (score 1):

first enable sql remote connections
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx

second open windows fw if you are using it on port 1433 (or whatever port you configured) for sql. 1433 is the default.